# How can I loop over the characters of two strings simultaneously?

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm using TASM 3.1 on windows 8 32 bit. I'm trying to read two characters from two different strings at a time. i.e. something like

```
for(I = 0, J = 0; I < N1 && J < N2; I++, J++)
{
    char c1 = string1[I];
    char c2 = stirng2[J];
}
```

I can loop through the characters of one string by doing

```
mov si, offset string
start:
  mov al, [si]
  cmp al, 0
  je end
  ;do stuff with character in al
  inc si
  jmp start
end:
```

and I declare the string at the top by

```
.data
  string db 'abracadabra'
```

How can I get a second string in there and iterate over it much like I'm doing with the first? It seems like `si` is the only sort of indexer I can use and that's not enough for two strings.

I'm trying to do things like compare two strings and print only characters which have same index and same value. Or do addition of large numbers represented as strings by adding the two characters on top of each other. How can I solve these sort of problems where I need to iterate over both strings at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note what you did in asm is pointer iteration, not indexing. Not sure why you need 2 variables `I` and `J` in the C code. You can just use 1.

```
    xor si, si
loop:
    mov al, [string1+si]
    mov dl, [string2+si]
    ; do something 
    inc si
    cmp si, [N1]
    jae done
    cmp si, [N2]
    jb loop
```

PS: In 16 bit x86 asm, you can also use `bx`, `di` and `bp` for indexing.
You could also precalculate `min(N1, N2)` of course.